# Programmatically modifying a Windows DLL's STRING TABLE in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, dll

I have a windows DLL which as a number of entries in the STRING TABLE. I want to be able to add to this table or modify this table but must do this in linux. I've taken a look at pefile but the functions for modification seem to be quite basic. I wonder if anyone knows of a good way to do this using only a linux box?

I'd like to do this in C if possible but perl or python would do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think a binary search and replace on your dll file will do the job on linux for modifying a string table.